# Easy way to convert str to float, round, then convert to int with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe like this:

```py
   Average
0    235.4
1    354.7
2    508.6
```

The values are strings.  I want to round them to the closest integer.

Is there any easier way to achieve this than this:

```py
df["Average"] = df["Average"].astype(float)
df["Average"] = df["Average"].round()
df["Average"] = df["Average"].astype(int)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain them in one line.  It doesn't get a whole lot simpler than that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Average': ['235.4','354.7','508.6']})
df.Average = df.Average.astype(float).round().astype(int)

#output:
   Average
0      235
1      355
2      509
```

Comment: Thanks (both you and @ThePyGuy). At least there's now one line instead of three. :)